# Copy List Initialization? Why does this compile?

Tags: c++

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, V16.5.2. I want to test [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

Please see the following test program:

```
#include <string>

void foo(std::string str) {}

int main() {

    foo( {"str1", "str2"} );

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles without error and warning. Why?

It gives a runtime error: `Expression: Transposed pointer range`

Can somebody please explain what is happening here?

---

Edit.

I dissasembled the code and run it in the debugger

```
    foo( {"str1", "str2"} );
00F739A8  sub         esp,1Ch  
00F739AB  mov         esi,esp  
00F739AD  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0C8h],esp  
00F739B3  lea         ecx,[ebp-0D1h]  
00F739B9  call        std::allocator<char>::allocator<char> (0F7136Bh)  
00F739BE  push        eax  
00F739BF  push        offset string "str2" (0F84DB8h)  
00F739C4  push        offset string "str1" (0F84E2Ch)  
00F739C9  mov         ecx,esi  
00F739CB  call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> ><char const *,0> (0F71569h)  
00F739D0  call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (0F71843h)  
00F739D5  add         esp,1Ch
```

It crashes at the first call to the constructor?

Comment: I don't understand your edit, but it looks like maybe a different question, so maybe you need to post a new question for it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`std::string` has a template constructor that builds a string from a begin/end iterator pair. String literals in C++ devolve down to `const char*`s. And pointers are iterators. Therefore, list initialization picked the begin/end pair constructor.

You got a runtime error because the two pointers do not actually create a valid range, which cannot be determined at compile-time (generally).

Comment: I understand. The range constructor. I disassembled and debuged the code. It crashes in the first call to the constructor. I do not understand ````<char const *,0>````. Can somebody please explain this?

Comment: THat means it's calling the `template< InputIt > (InputIt first, InputIt last,...)` constructor where the template parameter `iter` is `const char*`.... and apparently your implementation has a second integer parameter for some reason?

Comment: @ArminMontigny: Explain what? The disassembly is essentially irrelevant. Your code is stated to be syntactically valid but it gives undefined behavior due to not passing a valid range of iterators. You don't need to understand the disassembly to understand why your code is non-functional.

Answer (score 8):

`std::string` has a constructor overload in the form of

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

and this gets called because `"str1"` and  `"str2"` decay to `const char*`'s and `const char*` is an acceptable iterator type.

You get a crash because the "iterator range" you passed to the function is invalid.

Answer (score 7):

That use the constructor with iterators of [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (6.).

```
template< class InputIt >
constexpr basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last,
                        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

With [`InputIt` = `const char*`].

Then you have UB as the range `{"str1", "str2"}` is invalid.